# Using java replaceAll method to replace word in sentences with one regex

Tags: java, regex, replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace the "is" with "is not" in string but there is the exception that it should not replace "is" which is reside in other word.

Example

```
"This is an ant" --> "This is not an ant" [CORRECT]
"This is an ant" --> "This not is not an ant" [INCORRECT]
```

So far, what I did is

```
String result = str.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z0-9])is([^a-zA-Z0-9])","$1is not$2");
result = result.replaceAll("^is([^a-zA-Z0-9])","is not$1");
result = result.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z0-9])is$","$1is not");
result = result.replaceAll("^is$","is not");
```

But I think it is possible with only one regex but I can't figure it out.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use word boundary (`\b`):

```
result = str.replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "is not");
```

NOTE: `\` should be escaped. Otherwise it matches backspace (U+0008).

See [Demo](http://ideone.com/Q5HNcK).

Answer (score 2):

```
result = str.replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "is not");
```

`\b` matches word-boundaries.

[Edit]: Thanks @Falsetru for the notice on escaping - you're right, of course!